# Populating a table used in a many-to-many relationship from other tables

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a base table that does not respect the normal forms (think Excel tables).

It contains a list of columns with true/false fields of the same nature and also has a field containing a comma-delimited list of abbreviations. Both of these could be candidates for forming extra tables.

For the abbreviations What I'm currently doing is manually entering a PK as follows (notice the static integer on the select):

```
INSERT recipe_ingredients(
recipe_id,
ingredient_id
)
SELECT uid, "1"
FROM ingredients
-- ANCHO = Anchovies
WHERE ingredients_abbrev LIKE "%ANCHO%" ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE recipe_id = recipe_id
```

Is there a way I could run a query that uses all three tables so the intermediary table is filled in one go?

Comment: do you need a technique in which the primary gets generated every time?

Comment: Change the table's PK  description to Auto Increment.

Comment: That is done in anticipation that users might want to add more "ingredients". The PK value here already exists and comes from a table structured as PK, Abbreviation. The insert here needs to fill a table which combines the id of a "recipe" with the id of an "ingredient" to form the many recipes linked to many ingredients relationship.

Comment: Please show us the content in all the three tables and what exactly you want..